# What if Bounty period expires with no answers?

Tags: support, bounty

I started a Bounty last week for my own question [What is Karna Guru](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21204/what-is-karna-guru?s=3%7C29.7596). But the period expired today and I cannot get any answers also the amount of Bounty got lost. No one got the Bounty .

So in this case, what happened to the Bounty?

Comment: You don't get the bounty amount back if no one answers.  The bounty amount is just lost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visit the help centre about [bounty](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> #### What happens when I start a bounty?
>
> The bountied question will appear with a special indicator in all question lists, and it will also be visible on the homepage Featured tab for 7 days. Part of what you’re “paying for” with the bounty is to get additional attention for your question, over and beyond what a normal question gets. In that regard, a bounty **does not guarantee a response, and reputation refunds are not available if no answers are received as a result of the bounty.**

For comprehensive information to all the questions regarding bounty, I recommend visiting [How does bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/260388):

> #### What happens if there's no answer after the bounty period?
>
> If after the end of the bounty period a question has no answers, **no bounty will be awarded and the question will no longer be featured.**
>
> Part of what you're "paying for" with a bounty is for higher question visibility and increased answerer motivation. **A bounty does not guarantee a response and is not refunded if none are received.**

So, if there is no answer at the end of bounty period, bounty will bot be awarded and the bounty amount will be lost and not refunded.

I see your question on Karna Guru is not answered, You may discuss in chat room where sites users may help you.