# After how much time the "Start a Bounty" option appears?

Tags: discussion, support

When a new question is asked, then after how much time the "Start a Bounty" link appears?

Some time it appears immediately after asking a question.
I recently asked a question for which I didn't see a link for that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've not fully read links of [help-centre](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) and [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/260388) I mentioned in [previous answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/974/277)

start bounty option is made available 2 days after question was asked.

> #### How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?
>
> A bounty can be started on a question **two days after the question was asked**.

It's never available immediately.